# Update sequence number mismatch; requested USN = 2, database USN = 3

Tags: filenet-content-engine

I am using Filenet 4.5.1 I have a module in my project where we move the contents from a folder to a newly created folder , and then delete them from old folder.

```
        ObjectStore objectStore;
        ReferentialContainmentRelationship toRcr = null;
        ReferentialContainmentRelationship fromRcr = null;
        DocumentSet documentSet;
        Iterator documentIterator;
        documentSet = fromFolder.get_ContainedDocuments();
        documentIterator = documentSet.iterator();
        Document document;
        while(documentIterator.hasNext())
            {   

             document = (Document) documentIterator.next();
             toRcr = toFolder.file(document,AutoUniqueName.AUTO_UNIQUE, document.getClassName(),DefineSecurityParentage.DO_NOT_DEFINE_SECURITY_PARENTAGE);

             toRcr.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
             toFolder.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
             fromRcr = fromFolder.unfile(document);
             fromFolder.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
            }
```

But, here toFolder.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH); is not being executed properly and an exception is coming

Exception in FNServices.getOldFileFolderObject() : The object {ADF64C74-F80D-4BD7-8A58-86699C66BFAC} has been modified since it was retrieved. Update sequence number mismatch; requested USN = 2, database USN = 3.

Here , the object refers to the new folder created.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from IBM documentation, I believe you should create your folder first, and then worry about the filing after.

```
ObjectStore objectStore;
    ReferentialContainmentRelationship toRcr = null;
    ReferentialContainmentRelationship fromRcr = null;
    DocumentSet documentSet;
    Iterator documentIterator;
    documentSet = fromFolder.get_ContainedDocuments();
    documentIterator = documentSet.iterator();
    Document document;
    toFolder.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
    fromFolder.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
    while(documentIterator.hasNext())
        {   

         document = (Document) documentIterator.next();
         toRcr = toFolder.file(document,AutoUniqueName.AUTO_UNIQUE, document.getClassName(),DefineSecurityParentage.DO_NOT_DEFINE_SECURITY_PARENTAGE);

         toRcr.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);

         fromRcr = fromFolder.unfile(document);
         fromRcr.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
        }
```

Take a look here: [Working with Containment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_4.5.1/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/guide/containment_procedures.htm?cp=SSNW2F_4.5.1%2F5-5-2-1-5-1)